# How Do I Remove Duplicate and Get the Max Value After a SUM() + Group By? postgresql

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

| machine_name | reward_points | recipt_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LEKKSERVER01 | 57.5 | 43543 |
| LEKKSERVER01 | 34 | 53453 |
| HERMSERVER | 23 | 35353 |
| IKOYSERVER01 | 24 | 35636 |
| IKOYSERVER01 | 20.5 | 63653 |

When I used this query

```sql
SELECT l.machine_name, 
       t.points
FROM
(
    SELECT machine_name, 
           SUM(reward_points) as points
    FROM loyalty
    GROUP BY machine_name
) t 
JOIN loyalty l ON l.machine_name = t.machine_name
```

I get the below result

| machine_name | points |
| --- | --- |
| LEKKSERVER01 | 91.5 |
| LEKKSERVER01 | 91.5 |
| HERMSERVER | 23 |
| IKOYSERVER01 | 44.5 |
| IKOYSERVER01 | 44.5 |

However, the result I am expecting is this.

| machine_name | points |
| --- | --- |
| LEKKSERVER01 | 91.5 |
| HERMSERVER | 23 |
| IKOYSERVER01 | 44.5 |

My question is,
How can I remove the duplicates and possibly return the row with the highest points?

I would like to return something like this

| machine_name | points |
| --- | --- |
| LEKKSERVER01 | 91.5 |

Comment: How would you handle a tie?

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Mysql, you tagged both? Please add the correct specific RDBMS tag.

Comment: `SELECT machine_name, SUM(reward_points) as points  FROM loyalty GROUP BY machine_name ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `JOIN` and use `HAVING`

```
SELECT machine_name, 
           SUM(reward_points) as points
FROM loyalty
GROUP BY machine_name
HAVING SUM(reward_points) >= all (
    SELECT SUM(reward_points)
    FROM loyalty
    GROUP BY machine_name
)
```

This solution can return more than one row if there is more than one `machine_name` with the highest points (i.e. it handles ties). The equivalent SQL in PostgreSql 13+ should be

```
SELECT machine_name, 
           SUM(reward_points) as points
FROM loyalty
GROUP BY machine_name
ORDER BY points DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `max(t.points)` along with `group by machine_name`:

```
SELECT l.machine_name,
       Max(t.points) AS points
FROM   (SELECT machine_name,
               Sum(reward_points) AS points
        FROM   loyalty
        GROUP  BY machine_name) t
       JOIN loyalty l
         ON l.machine_name = t.machine_name
GROUP  BY machine_name
```

To get only one row that has the highest `points`:

```
SELECT l.machine_name,
       Max(t.points) AS points
FROM   (SELECT machine_name,
               Sum(reward_points) AS points
        FROM   loyalty
        GROUP  BY machine_name) t
       JOIN loyalty l
         ON l.machine_name = t.machine_name
GROUP  BY machine_name
ORDER  BY points DESC
LIMIT  1
```